# Playing audio from a constantly changing numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pyaudio

I have a numpy array which is continuously growing in size, with a function adding data to it every so often. This array actually is sound data, which I would like to play, not after the array is done, but while it is still growing. Is there a way I can do that using pyaudio? I have tried implementing a callback, but without success. It gives me choppy audio with delay

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps intercept the event or pipeline that appends the data to your array.

In order to get rid of the choppiness you will need some kind of intermediate buffer - imagine that data comes at random intervals - sometimes there will be several data points added simultaneously and sometimes no data for a period of time, but on longer timescales there will be some average inflow value. This is a standard practice done in streaming services to increase video quality.

Adjust the buffer size and this should eliminate the choppiness. This will of course introduce initial delay in playing the data, i.e. it won't be "live", but might be close to live with less choppiness.